# Python JSON парсинг конкретной переменной

Tags: python, json, парсер

У меня к примеру есть такой json:

```
{
  "Name": Vladimir,
  "Time": "15:34",
  "Date": "12.04.1997"
}{
  "Name": Egor,
  "Time": "12:11",
  "Date": "05.02.1994"
}
и т.д
```

Как мне с помощью питона отпарсить только значения переменной **"Name" + "Date"**? С учетом что таких строк jsonов более ста, и все **уникальные**.

Comment: Что такое "отпарсить"? Получить значения этих полей? https://stackoverflow.com/q/16129652/13970074

Comment: Да,в моем случае это получить значение переменной "Name" и "Date",спасибо за ссылку сейчас взгляну. @dIm0n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Скажите как должен выглядеть конечный результат?
2. Дело имеем с json или x-ndjson? Я так понимаю, что с первым, тогда формат должен быть примерно такой [{}, {}]

Если результатом должен быть кортеж вида (имя, дата), то простое решение может выглядеть так:

```
import json

# где response ваш json
result = [
    (i['Name'], i['Date']) for i in json.loads(response)
]
# [('Vladimir', '12.04.1997'), ('Egor', '05.02.1994')]
```

Для более сложных случаев можно посмотреть на библиотеку jsonpath-ng. Поиграться с путями можно [здесь](https://jsonpath.com/). Быстрый пример без разбивки по кортежам:

```
import json
from jsonpath_ng import parse

expression = parse('$[*][Name,Date]')
result = [
    match.value for match in expression.find(response)
]
# ['Vladimir', '12.04.1997', 'Egor', '05.02.1994']
```