# Работа с JSON, вывод определенных данных

Tags: python, json

Дан файл json - listaudio.json. В нем находятся примерно такие данные:

`{'id': 12345, 'owner_id': 67890, 'url': '', 'artist': 'ExampleArtist', 'title': 'ExampleTitle', 'duration': 320}, {'id': 45624, 'owner_id': 67890, 'url': '', 'artist': 'ExampleArtist2', 'title': 'ExampleTitle2', 'duration': 243}`

нужно вывести только данные artist и title, т.е. вывод должен выглядеть так:

```
ExampleArtist - ExampleTitle
ExampleArtist2 - ExampleTitle2
```

Подскажите, как это сделать, используя python

Comment: [Предыдущий вопрос с меткой json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1157452/398802)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё очень просто:

```py
import json

with open('listaudio.json') as f:
  json_object = json.load(f)

for elem in json_object:
  print('{0} - {1}'.format(elem['artist'], elem['title']))
```

Сперва мы открываем файл для чтения `open('listaudio.json')`, далее получаем json объект из него через встроенный модуль `json.load(f)`.

```py
for elem in json_object:
  print('{0} - {1}'.format(elem['artist'], elem['title']))
```

Через этот цикл, мы проходимся по каждому элементу данного json массива и выводим его артиста, а также название.

Только не забудьте, что в json используются **двойные** кавычки, так что в файле должны быть не одинарные, а **двойные**!

Answer (score 0):

```py
# pip install jsonpath-ng (если не установлен)

from jsonpath_ng import parse

json_data = [
    {"id": 12345, "owner_id": 67890, "url": '', "artist": "ExampleArtist", "title": "ExampleTitle", "duration": 320},
    {"id": 45624, "owner_id": 67890, "url": '', "artist": "ExampleArtist2", "title": "ExampleTitle2", "duration": 243}
]

titles = [m.value for m in parse('$..title').find(json_data)]
artists = [m.value for m in parse('$..artist').find(json_data)]


for artist, title in zip(artists, titles):
    print(artist, title, sep=' - ')
```